# Como instalar Qt para MSVC sem o IDE da Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, qt

É possível instalar Qt e o compilador do MSVC sem instalar o IDE da Microsoft?

Eu baixei está versão do [Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 694 MB)](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.0.exe) e instalei, porém não tenho muito conhecimento de produtos microsoft, acredito que tenha que instalar o o MSVS 2013, porém ao instalar acabo instalando IDE da Microsoft junto. É possível instalar ou baixar apenas o "compilador"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Não é possível**.

O Windows SDK costumava vir com o compilador em linha de comando, separado do Visual Studio. Mas a partir da versão 8, não vem mais com o compilador. A solução no entanto é simples: Instale o Visual Studio. Você não precisa abrir ou usar a IDE, apenas deixe instalada.

Se realmente preferir, pode instalar a versão 7 do Windows SDK, mas não recomendo (e provavelmente não será compatível com essa versão do Qt).